# Pymc3, fitting a piecewise function

Tags: python, pymc3, mcmc, piecewise

I am attempting to fit a piecewise function using pymc3 but am having trouble with the syntax. The current state of my code is shown in the image below, which is generating an error. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Here are links to the [current state of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szstX.png) and the [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zreW7.png).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.